# how to delete the line after a special number?

Tags: notepad++, regex

How I can delete the numbers and characters more than a special number by regex in notepad++?

This is a part of text:

```
1230 مهندسی برق-تبریز
126 مهندسی کامپیوتر-شریف
234 مهندسی کامپیوتر-تهران
786 مهندسی مکانیک تبریز
654 مهندسی برق-تبریز
5644 مهندسی شیمی-تبریز
543 مهندسی شیمی-تهران
1500 مهندسی برق-شهید مدنی 
365  مهندسی نفت-امیرکبیر
7654 شیمی-تبریز
```

and I want the numbers and characters less than for example 700 to have this list:

```
126 مهندسی کامپیوتر-شریف
234 مهندسی کامپیوتر-تهران
654 مهندسی برق-تبریز
543 مهندسی شیمی-تهران
365  مهندسی نفت-امیرکبیر
```

which regex code can prepare this list?

Answer (score 0):

Read first 4 digit, if less than 700, add it to variable x,  else go next line. Do it until finished all text.  Your variable x will ha e the answer u need. U can set extra filters also,u can rearrange output before send line to the variable x.

Comment: I want regex code for it because I don't know about strings.
How I can do this explanation by these codes?